# how to separate a map collection into multiple lists

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, linked-list, hashmap

I have a Map collection that contains a list of productId, quantity, and no of orders in the form **productId=[quantity, no of orders]**. the map collection is like

```
{pid0000013=[1238, 1], pid000003=[581, 1], pid0000034=[2929, 1], pid0000032=[1357, 1], pid0000051=[799, 1], pid0000050=[518, 1], pid0000019=[836, 1], pid0000018=[946, 1], pid0000039=[1992, 1], pid0000016=[3026, 2], pid0000037=[528, 1], pid0000014=[1966, 1], pid0000036=[1632, 1], pid0000046=[2472, 2], pid0000045=[733, 1], pid0000023=[2308, 1], pid0000044=[3205, 2], pid0000043=[2521, 2], pid0000021=[369, 1], pid0000042=[822, 1], pid0000041=[1515, 1], pid0000040=[491, 1], pid0000029=[2230, 1], pid0000028=[645, 1], pid0000049=[190, 1], pid0000027=[1897, 1], pid0000048=[1594, 1], pid0000026=[1536, 1], pid0000047=[3071, 2]}
```

for each productId, there is a quantity and no, of orders. the code was returned in java.
my requirement is I want to separate productIds,quantities, and no, of orders into 3 different lists like

```
[pid0000013,pid000003,pid0000034,pid0000032,pid0000051 and so on]
```

```
[1238,581,2929,1357,799 and so on]
```

```
[1,1,1,1,1 and so on]
```

the quantity and no, of orders should match the productId to which they are related.
how shall I achieve this in java?

Comment: So, let me see if I understand you correctly...  you desire to take data where information that is relevant to each other is held together and convert it into parallel arrays? If so, why? You'd be taking a fairly robust data structure and converting it into something much more brittle, into an "anti-pattern", if you will.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> productToOrderInfo = new HashMap<>();
        productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000013", List.of(1238, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid000003", List.of(581, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000034", List.of(2929, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000032", List.of(1357, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000051", List.of(799, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000050", List.of(518, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000019", List.of(836, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000018", List.of(946, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000039", List.of(1992, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000016", List.of(3026, 2)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000037", List.of(528, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000014", List.of(1966, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000036", List.of(1632, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000046", List.of(2472, 2)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000045", List.of(733, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000023", List.of(2308, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000044", List.of(3205, 2)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000043", List.of(2521, 2)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000021", List.of(369, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000042", List.of(822, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000041", List.of(1515, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000040", List.of(491, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000029", List.of(2230, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000028", List.of(645, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000049", List.of(190, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000027", List.of(1897, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000048", List.of(1594, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000026", List.of(1536, 1)); productToOrderInfo.put("pid0000047", List.of(3071, 2));
        System.out.printf("productToOrderInfo = %s%n", productToOrderInfo);
        List<String> productIds = List.copyOf(productToOrderInfo.keySet());
        System.out.printf("productIds = %s%n", productIds);
        List<Integer> quantities = productToOrderInfo.values().stream().map(s -> s.get(0)).toList();
        System.out.printf("quantities = %s%n", quantities);
        List<Integer> numberOfOrders = productToOrderInfo.values().stream().map(s -> s.get(1)).toList();
        System.out.printf("numberOfOrders = %s%n", numberOfOrders);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
productToOrderInfo = {pid0000013=[1238, 1], pid000003=[581, 1], pid0000034=[2929, 1], pid0000032=[1357, 1], pid0000051=[799, 1], pid0000050=[518, 1], pid0000019=[836, 1], pid0000018=[946, 1], pid0000039=[1992, 1], pid0000016=[3026, 2], pid0000037=[528, 1], pid0000014=[1966, 1], pid0000036=[1632, 1], pid0000046=[2472, 2], pid0000045=[733, 1], pid0000023=[2308, 1], pid0000044=[3205, 2], pid0000043=[2521, 2], pid0000021=[369, 1], pid0000042=[822, 1], pid0000041=[1515, 1], pid0000040=[491, 1], pid0000029=[2230, 1], pid0000028=[645, 1], pid0000049=[190, 1], pid0000027=[1897, 1], pid0000048=[1594, 1], pid0000026=[1536, 1], pid0000047=[3071, 2]}
productIds = [pid0000013, pid000003, pid0000034, pid0000032, pid0000051, pid0000050, pid0000019, pid0000018, pid0000039, pid0000016, pid0000037, pid0000014, pid0000036, pid0000046, pid0000045, pid0000023, pid0000044, pid0000043, pid0000021, pid0000042, pid0000041, pid0000040, pid0000029, pid0000028, pid0000049, pid0000027, pid0000048, pid0000026, pid0000047]
quantities = [1238, 581, 2929, 1357, 799, 518, 836, 946, 1992, 3026, 528, 1966, 1632, 2472, 733, 2308, 3205, 2521, 369, 822, 1515, 491, 2230, 645, 190, 1897, 1594, 1536, 3071]
numberOfOrders = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```